# C Program - printf overlapping with other printf chars

Tags: c, file, printf, system-calls

I'm working on a program in C that will open, read, and close a file with Linux system calls, and print the contents of the file(s) to the screen. The command format is

```
$ mycat [-bens] f1 [f2 ...].
```

The switches are as follows:

- `-b` displays the line number for each non-blank line, starting at 1
- `-e` displays a '$' at the end of each line
- `-n` displays the line number for every line
- `-s` removes all empty lines from the output (effectively single-spacing the output)

The problem is that when I use the `-b` or `-n` switch, `printf` appears to be "overlapping" the line number with what the buffer is trying to print from the text file itself.

Here is the code I have written for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 4096

void oops(char *, char *);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int fd, numRead, curr, i, c;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};
    extern char *optarg; 
    extern int optind;
    int tmpS = 0;
    int tmpB = 0;
    int bFlag = 0;
    int eFlag = 0;
    int nFlag = 0;
    int sFlag = 0;
    int bLineNum = 1;
    int nLineNum = 1;

    /* Flag processing in argument list */
    while( (c = getopt(ac, av, "bens")) != -1)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'b':
                bFlag = 1;
                break;
            case 'e':
                eFlag = 1;
                break;
            case 'n':
                nFlag = 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                sFlag = 1;
                break;
            default:
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Scan through each argument after flag */
    for(i = optind; i < ac; i++)
    {
        /* Error handling when opening each file */
        if((fd = open(av[i], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
            oops("Cannot open ", av[i]);

        /* Read from file to buffer, until end is reached */
        while( (numRead = read(fd, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
        {

            /* Once buffer is filled, process each address in buffer */
            for(curr = 0; curr < BUFFERSIZE; curr++)
            {
            /* sFlag squeezes output, eliminating blank lines */
            if(sFlag && buf[curr] == '\n')
            {
                tmpS = curr + 1;

                while(buf[tmpS] != '\r')
                {
                    if(isspace(buf[tmpS]))
                        tmpS++;
                    else
                        break;
                }

                curr = tmpS + 1;
            }

            /* nFlag numbers each line, starting from 1 */
            if(nFlag && buf[curr] == '\n')
                printf("%d ", nLineNum++);

            /* eFlag puts a '$' at the end of every line */
            if(eFlag && buf[curr] == '\r')
                printf(" $");

            /* bFlag numbers every non-blank line, starting from 1 */
            if(bFlag && buf[curr] == '\n')
            {
                tmpB = curr + 1;

                if(isEmptyLine(buf, tmpB))
                    printf("%d ", bLineNum++);

            }

            /* Print the current character in the buffer address */
                printf("%c", buf[curr]);
            }
        }

        if(numRead == -1)
            oops("Read error from ", av[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void oops(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s ", s1);
    perror(s2);
    exit(1);
}

int isEmptyLine(char *buf, int tmp)
{
    while(buf[tmp] != '\n')
    {
        if(!isspace(buf[tmp]))
            return 0;
        tmp++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Sample input (file1.txt):

```
An excerpt from LEARNING DOS FOR THE COMPLETE NOVICE, by Steven Woas, copyright 1993.  

1.   Change to the compressed drive and then issue a CHKDSK
     command like so:

           c: <ENTER>

           chkdsk /f <ENTER>

     The /F tells DOS to fix errors. 

     Another option is to do it like so:

           dblspace /chkdsk /f  <ENTER>

     A shortcut for the DBLSPACE /CHKDSK /F command is:

           dblspace /chk /f  <ENTER>
```

Output with -n flag on and running:

```
sh-4.2$ ./main -n file1.txt    

1  excerpt from LEARNING DOS FOR THE COMPLETE NOVICE, by Steven Woas, copyright 1993.                                                                                                                                                                  
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
3    Change to the compressed drive and then issue a CHKDSK                                                                                                                                                                                            
4    command like so:                
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
6          c: <ENTER>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
8          chkdsk /f <ENTER>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
10   The /F tells DOS to fix errors.                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
12   Another option is to do it like so:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
14         dblspace /chkdsk /f  <ENTER>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
16   A shortcut for the DBLSPACE /CHKDSK /F command is:                                                                                                                                                                                                
17                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
18         dblspace /chk /f  <ENTER>
```

I'm having the same problem with the `-b` flag and I don't know why. Does it have to do with `\r` and `\n` not being read properly?

Comment: I don't see the "overlap" you mention. How *should* the output look like?

Comment: maybe you shouldn't print the `\r` chars at all.

Comment: `read()` tells you how many bytes it has actually read, and you dutifully record that in variable `numRead`.  How come you don't use that to determine how many bytes from the buffer to process?

Comment: On line '1' with -n flag, it's missing 'An' in the beginning. On line '3', it's missing the '1.' before 'Change

Also, when using the -b flag, I'm having similar overlap issues. -b also misses the 2nd and last lines of the text file when printing line numbers, and I'm confused as to why.

Comment: That's a good point John - I did change the second for() loop to use numRead instead of BUFFERSIZE, but I'm still having problems with the proper line numbers being printed, and I can't figure out why. Thanks for mentioning that about numRead.

Comment: Since you need to process lines, why not use a line-oriented input function — [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) from standard C or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) from POSIX.  That will be easier than using `read()` which doesn't care in the slightest about lines. I strongly suspect you are running into problems with carriage returns. One advantage of using standard I/O is that those functions, working on text files, map CRLF line endings to newlines. OTOH, that may be a disadvantage here.

Comment: Even if you should work with binary mode files, unless you need to recognize Mac format files (CR only at ends of lines), the `getline()` function allows you to work sanely (but `fgets()` does not; you can't tell how many bytes are relevant after a null byte).

Answer (score 0):

Your program exhibits the misbehavior you describe for files with Windows- (DOS-)style line endings (`\r\n`), but different misbehavior for files with UNIX-style line endings (`\n` alone) and yet different misbehavior for files with MacOS class-style line endings (`\r` alone).  Inasmuch as you seem to be assuming Windows-style line endings overall, I'll focus on that.

Consider what happens when your program reaches the end of a line.  It first processes the `\r` character, ultimately printing it.  This causes the output position to return to the beginning of the line (which is possible because the standard output is line-buffered by default).  You then print the line number, overwriting whatever may have been there before, and finally print the `\n` character, causing the buffer to be flushed and the output to move to the next line.

You probably ought to recognize the `\r\n` *sequence* as a line ending, instead of trying to handle these characters individually.  That may prove to be a bit challenging, as you need to account for the possibility that the pair is split across two `read()`s, but that's shouldn't be too hard.  This will also give you the opportunity to consider what to do if you encounter a lone `\n` and / or a lone `\r`, which your program could handle more gracefully than it now does.

Comment: I'm actually dealing with UNIX files, as I'm writing this program on a Raspberry Pi 2 (sorry, I should have specified this from the beginning). So that should make things even easier, as I just need to find \n characters. But using the -b flag is still causing headaches - I don't know why it's giving some non-empty lines a number, but others it won't

Comment: @Elliot, none of that makes a difference to my answer.  Moreover, (1) the program you presented produces the misbehavior you describe only if the input file has DOS-style line termination.  I conclude that's what it has.  The fact that you are running the software on your Pi has nothing to do with it.  (2) Your program is clearly *designed* for use with input that has DOS-style line termination (notwithstanding that it is broken).  Again, the fact that you are running it on your Pi has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks to you I figured it out - it turns out the input file line termination styles depends on what system the file was created on, not what system it's currently being input to. Since I created the input file on Windows, it had DOS-style line termination, making the program logic different than if I had just created it on UNIX. I recreated the input files on the Pi, and then changed my logic to just deal with \n, and it made everything much easier!! Dealing with \r\n line termination proved to be rather painful...